# How to remove bubble from Google Map

Tags: google-maps

I've done some searching and it seems that you need to remove the iwloc part of the path, but I can't find it anywhere!

```
<iframe width="725" height="300" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=ightham&amp;aq=&amp;sll=51.223215,0.33516&amp;sspn=0.048003,0.132093&amp;gl=uk&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=Ightham,+Kent,+United+Kingdom&amp;t=m&amp;z=14&amp;ll=51.287109,0.286445&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
```

Comment: This is all undocumented. If you want to include a Google Map on your site, consider using the Google Maps API instead: https://developers.google.com/maps/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the:

```
&q=ightham
```

That removes the bubble for me:

https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&aq=&sll=51.223215,0.33516&sspn=0.048003,0.132093&gl=uk&ie=UTF8&hq=&hnear=Ightham,+Kent,+United+Kingdom&t=m&z=14&ll=51.287109,0.286445&output=embed

Answer (score 4):

I think `&iwloc=near` at the end is what you need. This example also shows that you really just need the postcode and the magnification i.e `z=10`

```
<iframe width="400" scrolling="no" height="300" frameborder="0" src="https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?hl=en&q=so21+1aj&z=10&output=embed&iwloc=near" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"></iframe>
```

Check this [live example](http://www.iphonerepairwinchester.co.uk/iPhoneRepairHampshire.htm)